# Как выполнить код, находящийся в переменной String на groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

Есть переменная и код в ней. (Код вводит пользователь в textArea) Как выполнить этот код на groovy. В этом коде возможен вызов методов классов на java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.ImportCustomizer;
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration;
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;
import groovy.lang.Binding;

...

// По необходимости надо добавить import в скрипт
ImportCustomizer ic = new ImportCustomizer();
ic.addImports("my.package.MyClass");

// Заготовленный import для скрипта помещается в конфигурацию
// компилятора groovy
CompilerConfiguration cc = new CompilerConfiguration();
cc.addCompilationCustomizers(ic);

// Связывает объекты программы с переменными скрипта
Binding gb = new Binding();
gb.setVariable("myObject", myObject);

// Создать shell, используя заготовленные биндинги и конфигурацию компилятора
GroovyShell gsh = new GroovyShell(gb, cc);

// Собственно выполнение скрипта
gsh.evaluate(scriptText);
// Можно даже вернуть какой-то результат
Object res = gsh.evaluate(scriptText);
```

При таком биндинге в скрипте не должно быть никакого объявления переменной `myObject`: ни def myObject, ни MyClass myObject. Она уже как бы объявлена, просто сразу используйте её: `myObject.method(); myObject.prop = ...`

Comment: Спасибо огромное)

Comment: IDEA подчеркивает ошибкой  gb.setVariable("myObject", myObject);

Comment: Конечно могут быть какие-то неточности в примере, но `Binding gb = new Binding(); gb.setVariable(...);` копия с рабочей программы, только параметры названы по-другому. Убедитесь 1) что у Вас имеется объект myObject (или как там он у Вас называется по-настоящему), 2) что Binding - это `groovy.lang.Binding`, а не какой-нибудь другой биндинг, 3) может groovy какой-нибудь старой версии, где нет метода setVariable(), но этого я не могу знать наверняка, потому что не интересуюсь историей развития groovy. Других причин не могу предположить.